# mysql to xml using php

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Is there anyone know how can I export each row of a mysql select to each xml file?

I tried some php scripts but in all, only one file were created.

The table content is:

```
+----+----------------+---------------------------------------+-----------+
| id | colum1         | colum2                                | colum3    |
+----+----------------+---------------------------------------+-----------+
|  1 |     2147483647 | user1@user.com                        | Ident1    |
|  2 |     2147483648 | user2@user.com                        | Ident2    |
|  3 |     2147483649 | user3@user.com                        | Ident3    |
|  4 |     2147483650 | user4@user.com                        | Ident4    |
|  5 |     2147483651 | user5@user.com                        | Ident5    |
+----+----------------+---------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Desired output is:

```
2147483647.xml
<account>
  <colum1>2147483647</colum1>
  <colum2>user1@user.com</colum2>
  <colum3>Ident1</colum3>
</account>

2147483648.xml
<account>
  <colum1>2147483648</colum1>
  <colum2>user2@user.com</colum2>
  <colum3>Ident2</colum3>
</account>

2147483649.xml
<account>
  <colum1>2147483649</colum1>
  <colum2>user3@user.com</colum2>
  <colum3>Ident3</colum3>
</account>

2147483650.xml
<account>
  <colum1>2147483650</colum1>
  <colum2>user4@user.com</colum2>
  <colum3>Ident4</colum3>
</account>

2147483651.xml
<account>
  <colum1>2147483651</colum1>
  <colum2>user5@user.com</colum2>
  <colum3>Ident5</colum3>
</account>
```

Comment: `"I tried some php scripts"` - We can help with that, but not unless you actually share the relevant code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is - in its current form - a "please write my code" type of question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php

// connect to mysql database
$database_server = "localhost";
$database_username = "username";
$database_password = "p@55W0rd";
$database_name = "example_database";

$mysqli_connection = new mysqli($database_server, $database_username, $database_password, $database_name);
if ($mysqli_connection->connect_error) {
    die($mysqli_connection->error());
}

// query data
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename;";

// get results
$result = $mysqli_connection->query($sql) or die($mysqli_connection->error);

// loop through rows
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $file = "$row[colum1].xml";
  $xml = "<account>\n";
    $xml .= "  <colum1>$row[colum1]</colum1>\n";
    $xml .= "  <colum2>$row[colum2]</colum2>\n";
    $xml .= "  <colum3>$row[colum3]</colum3>\n";
  $xml .= "</account>\n";
  // make sure permissions are set for directory so that server can write to file
  // i.e., apache2.4 running on ubuntu linux server
  // sudo chown -R :www-data foldername/
  file_put_contents($file,$xml);
}

?>
```

Comment: Congrats, you just did his work for him. Should have said, 'Google `php output xml`' instead. That's how I taught myself.

Comment: Thanks, but I felt like "go google it" doesn't really contribute any useful information. Moreover, he said that he had tried a couple of scripts already, so I'm sure he had already googled it. I just googled it, and got a couple of examples in the first page of results that weren't the way I would have implemented it, so I think a diversity of answers would be nice to determine what would best suit the use case. I thought a working example would be helpful.